# How to use Temporary Tables inside Begin Work

Tags: informix

I'm trying to create a script with a set of instructions inside a BEGIN WORK / COMMIT block, but for some reason the temporary table is not being created or is being deleted at some point:

this is the kind of script I'm working on:

```
-- PHASE2:
BEGIN WORK;
--create a temp table
CREATE temp table IF NOT EXISTS temp_users (
    reg_id char(2),
    cntry char(2),
    name varchar(25)
);

--insert to temp table
INSERT INTO temp_users(reg_id,cntry,name)
SELECT region,country,usr_name FROM user_data WHERE cntry = 'AU';

-- more work with the temp table below..
COMMIT;
```

But when I execute this script I'm getting an error because temp_users doesn't exists .

Comment: What is the version of Informix you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you're running into.  Using Informix 12.10.FC6 (time to upgrade — and then some) on Ubuntu 18.04, I can run this without error:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_data;
CREATE TABLE user_data
(
    region   CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    country  CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    cntry    CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    usr_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);

-- PHASE2:
BEGIN WORK;
--create a temp table
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_users (
    reg_id CHAR(2),
    cntry  CHAR(2),
    name   VARCHAR(25)
);
--insert to temp table
INSERT INTO temp_users(reg_id, cntry, name)
SELECT region, country, usr_name FROM user_data WHERE cntry = 'AU';
-- more work with the temp table below..
COMMIT;
```

I don't know why your `user_data` table has columns `country` and `cntry`; that's not obvious.

Try creating a temporary database (a database with a new name that you'll get rid of soon), and then run the script shown against it with DB-Access.  It should work, creating a trace like this (I used `stores` as the database and the file `xyz.sql` to contain the script):

```
$ dbaccess stores xyz

Database selected.


Table dropped.


Table created.


Started transaction.


Temporary table created.


0 row(s) inserted.


Data committed.


Database closed.

$
```

What do you get?

Comment: My problem is , even if I have the create temp table statement ,  when I try to insert data to the temp table (temp_users) I'm getting an error which says  the temp_users table doesn't exists

Comment: If you copy the code I showed (into a throwaway database — you probably don't want to drop your real `user_data` table), do you still get an error?

Comment: Yes, even inserting raw values (without a select) I'm getting the same error  
SQL Error [42000]: The specified table (temp_users) is not in the database.